# How Linux kernel 3.x manage ramdisk as block device?

Tags: block-device, ramdisk

I need a block device in RAM. I built a 3.x kernel and added the RAM block device driver. The number of RAM block device drive is 16 (by default) but when the kernel boots there is no ramx in `/sys/block` nor `/dev`. What's going on?

Comment: Please do not answer if you want to suggest `ramfs` or `tmpfs`.

Comment: Also tmpfs + losetup can simulate a block device.also this way provide `/dev/loop*` and `/sys/block/loop*`.Also tmpfs + losetup can simulate a block device.also this way provide `/dev/loop*` and `/sys/block/loop*`.also tmpfs is take some advantage than ram block device and ramfs
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you mean something like this:

Load the block ramdisk module, set the desired size in blocks using the `rd_size=...` parameter.

```
# modprobe brd rd_size=123456
```

...after this step `/dev/ram0` exists.

You now can put a filesystem on it.

```
# mkfs /dev/ram0
mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=1024 (log=0)
Fragment size=1024 (log=0)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
30976 inodes, 123456 blocks
6172 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=1
Maximum filesystem blocks=67371008
16 block groups
8192 blocks per group, 8192 fragments per group
1936 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        8193, 24577, 40961, 57345, 73729

Writing inode tables: done                            
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

This filesystem will be automatically checked every 38 mounts or
180 days, whichever comes first.  Use tune2fs -c or -i to override.
```

Mount it and check the space used and free...

```
# mount /dev/ram0 /mnt 
# df /mnt 
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/ram0               119539      1550    111817   2% /mnt
```

Comment: You are right. but what does the modprobe exactly do?

Comment: The `rd_size` parameter could be supplied to the kernel when booting if `brd` is compiled-in. The convenience of having `brd` as a module is that you can load and unload the module and supply different parameters (with `modprobe` like in this answer) on each initialization.

Comment: "what does the modprobe exactly do?"... `modprobe` loads the 'ramdisk driver', 'ramdisk support' or however you want to call it and is able to pass parameters to it, e.g. the ramdisk size in blocks...

Comment: Ok, modprobe handles loaded module and forces the brd to load. then the brd module loads some ram disk block device.

Comment: Hello, I was wondering if it is possible to use `-o dax` with `mount`. When I try it, after following the previous steps, I get `wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/ram1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`