# Mount filesystem with DAX enabled on RAM

Tags: filesystems, block-device, ram

I am trying to mount a filesystem with DAX feature on RAM.

I used [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157041/how-linux-kernel-3-x-manage-ramdisk-as-block-device) answer to load `brd` module and get `/dev/ram0.` Then I tried all 3 filesystems that support DAX: ext2, ext4 and xfs.

However, when I use `-o dax` flag with `mount`, I get this error: `wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/ram0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error`

With `dmesg | tail` I see the following issue: `(ram0): DAX unsupported by block device.`

Is this an incorrect way to achieve my initial goal, mounting a filesystem with DAX on RAM, or what could I be doing wrong?

I saw [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349769/linux-dax-direct-access-details) but I do not think `-t ramfs` does what I want, it won't appear in `df -h` list.

I use `5.10.0-14-amd64` linux kernel version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `DAX` support was removed from `brd` module. There is a [patch](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-nvdimm/patch/150949211688.24061.1197869674847507598.stgit@dwillia2-desk3.amr.corp.intel.com/) from 2017.